# Need to hide displayed div when I show others

Tags: javascript, html, hide, show

I am stuck. I have a page with 3 buttons, the 3 buttons do a couple things - they change the style of a div, and they also show/hide a content div. The changing of the div style works fine, but I am having issues with the content div. If you land on the page and click the "Our Brands" tab, then click the other 2 tabs, it works fine. If you land on the page, and click "What's New" or "About Us" first, then the show/hide does not work correctly - it does not until you actually click on "Our Brands."

http://www.adriancollins.net/clients/kennys/

Any help would be appreciated, I am a designer first, a developer about 9000th.

Show/Hide Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var _hidediv = null;
function showdiv(id) {
if(_hidediv)
    _hidediv();
var div = document.getElementById(id);
div.style.display = 'block';
_hidediv = function () { div.style.display = 'none'; };
}
</script>
```

Tab Divs

```
<div id="brand_button"><a href="#" onClick="showdiv('brands_content');     lower.className='blue';angle.className='blue_angle';return false"><img src="wp-content/uploads/2012/10/brands_button.png"></a></div>

<div id="whatsnew_button"><a href="#" onClick="showdiv('new_content');lower.className='black';angle.className='black_angle';return false"><img src="wp-content/uploads/2012/10/whatsnew_button.png"></a></div>

<div id="about_button"><a href="#" onClick="showdiv('about_content');lower.className='green';angle.className='green_angle';return false"><img src="wp-content/uploads/2012/10/about_button.png"></a></div>
```

Content Divs

```
<div id="brands_content">Content...</div>
<div id="new_content">Content...</div>
<div id="about_content">Content...</div>
```

CSS

```
#brands_content

{
position: relative;
display: block;
width: 990px;
top: 10px;
height: auto;
min-height: 800px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-right: auto;
border: 0px;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
z-index: 12;


}



#new_content

{
position: relative;
display: none;
width: 990px;
top: 10px;
height: auto;
min-height: 800px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-right: auto;
border: 0px;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
z-index: 999;
color: #fff;



}



#about_content

{
position: relative;
display: none;
width: 990px;
top: 10px;
height: auto;
min-height: 800px;    
margin-left: auto;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-right: auto;
border: 0px;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
z-index: 999;



}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your post.

Comment: YOu should clean that up a bit. I see the `showDiv` function defined twice. And it looks like there is a discrepancy between what is passed for the what's new button (new_content) and the corresponding div (whats_content)

Comment: Corrected, that was a typing error on my part and didn't reflect the actual site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You can change your body tag to be:

<body class="home page page-id-5 page-template page-template-home-php">

to

<body class="home page page-id-5 page-template page-template-home-php" onload="showdiv('brands_content')">
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution is to call showdiv('brands_content'); after all your html is loaded, then you have effectively clicked the "Our Brands" and everything behaves as desired.

```
<div id="brand_button"><a href="#" onClick="showdiv('brands_content');     lower.className='blue';angle.className='blue_angle';return false"><img src="wp-content/uploads/2012/10/brands_button.png"></a></div>

 <div id="whatsnew_button"><a href="#" onClick="showdiv('new_content');lower.className='black';angle.className='black_angle';return false"><img src="wp-content/uploads/2012/10/whatsnew_button.png"></a></div>

<div id="about_button"><a href="#" onClick="showdiv('about_content');lower.className='green';angle.className='green_angle';return false"><img src="wp-content/uploads/2012/10/about_button.png"></a></div>
showdiv('brands_content');
```

Comment: Would I place it just as above? Thanks again!

Comment: You would place it anywhere after the html containing the anchors